# How do I dispose all of the controls in Panels and tabPages in winforms app

Tags: c#

I have a winforms C# app with a bunch of Panels that have tabPages and controls within those tabPages. They are set like this in the designer.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tcMerchantApplication;
```

...

```
this.tcMerchantApplication.Controls.Add(this.tabPage0);
this.tcMerchantApplication.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
this.tcMerchantApplication.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
this.tcMerchantApplication.Controls.Add(this.tabPage3);
```

...

```
this.tabPage0.Controls.Add(this.tlpTabPage0);
```

...

```
this.tlpTabPage0.Controls.Add(this.label79, 0, 1);
this.tlpTabPage0.Controls.Add(this.label86, 1, 5);
this.tlpTabPage0.Controls.Add(this.label84, 1, 4);
```

Before the form closes I am trying to dispose of all of the controls like this:

```
            foreach (Control ctl in tlpTabPage0.Controls)
            {
                ctl.Dispose();
                ctl.Controls.Clear();
            }
            foreach (Control ctl in tlpTabPage1.Controls)
            {
                ctl.Dispose();
                ctl.Controls.Clear();
            }
            foreach (TabPage tp in tcMerchantApplication.TabPages)
            {
                foreach (Control ctl in tp.Controls)
                {
                    ctl.Dispose();
                    ctl.Controls.Clear();
                }
                tp.Dispose();
                tp.Controls.Clear();
            }
```

Do I have to iterate through all of the children first and then the parent?

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to dispose of objects in a collection. Use a backwards `for` loop. `Controls.Clear()` has no effect if you run this code when the Form closes. Otherwise, it just clears the internal buffer (not necessary, but it doesn't hurt). -- I suggest you dispose of one TagPage (or any other Container) and verify whether its child Controls are disposed or not. I think it's more interesting for you to test it directly. ++ As of now, you're disposing of half of the Controls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to dispose all controls when closing the application anyway, but I'd do something like `panel1.Controls.Clear()` (didn't check correct syntax)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am not closing the app. I am closing the form. The form opens and closes multiple times throughout the day. After a while the app crashes with windows handles error because none of the controls in the TabPages or panels are disposed

Comment: This sounds interesting to me and I've never encoutered such a bug. I'll try to do some research and come back if i found something new